# Can't get rid of a deleted Settings reference in DataSet.Designer.vb

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2008

I had a connection string to a MS Access DB file, Foo.accdb, defined and used in my project.  It was defined as a connection string Setting in the Settings section of my project properties.  The program referenced the connection string setting and everything worked fine.

Then I decided  to replace Foo.accdb with two different DB files, A.accdb and B.accdb each of which would be used under different circumstances.  I added connection strings for them in Settings and removed the Setting definition for Foo.accdb connection string.

The name of my application is Foo and the name of the Foo.accdb connection string was FooConnectionString.

But now when I build the program both in debugger and for release I get the following error message:

```
'FooConnectionString' is not a member of 'Foo.My.MySettings'.
```

The offending reference, in file FooDataSet.Designer.vb, is:

```
    <Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()>  _
    Private Sub InitConnection()
        Me._connection = New Global.System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
        Me._connection.ConnectionString = Global.Foo.My.MySettings.Default.FooConnectionString
    End Sub
```

What is going on here?  FooConnectionString is not in any other file in the project directory nor in the My Project subdir.  I completely got rid of it in my code and in my project properties yet it persists in FooDataSet.Designer.vb (whatever that is).

While researching this on the web I saw a recommendation to select the FooDataSet.xsd file, right click it and execute the "Run Custom Tool" option.  I did this and it appears to rebuild FooDataSet.Designer.vb (the time stamp changes) but the problem persists.

I also tried removing the offending reference by manually editing FooDataSet.Designer.vb but that gave me some other error message.

Why is this old reference staying around and what can I do about it?

This is a standalone app. I'm using VS2008 Standard Ed., VB.Net 3.5

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the FooDataSet XSD file in a text editor. Right click on dataset in the solution explorer and select "Open With..." and the select XML (text) Editor or open it outside the solution.

Look for the `<Connections>` tag near the top of the file. Remove the line that looks like this

```
<Connection AppSettingsObjectName="Settings" AppSettingsPropertyName="FooConnectionString" ConnectionStringObject="" IsAppSettingsProperty="true" Modifier="Assembly" Name="FooConnectionString(Settings)" ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I did as you suggest, first deleting only that line and then deleting both of the <Connections> and </Connections> tags but I get the following error at compile: "Custom tool error:Failed to generate code.  Exception of type "System.Data.Design.InternalException' was thrown."

Comment: @RaleighBoy I'm sorry about that. Instead of deleting the connection try changing it to either A.accdb or B.accdb

Comment: Conrad, Yup, that did it.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Raleigh. No problem glad I could help. BTW since you're new you might want to check out this post on [accepting answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235), not that I'm lobbying you to mark my answer as accepted ;)